# Failed patch changed my Git Bash prompt, how do I revert it?

Tags: git, git-am

I tried to apply a patch using `git am <my.patch`, but it failed.

Now I'm getting this in Git Bash:

```
sashoalm@SASHOALM-PC /c/Workspace/MyProject (master|AM 1/1)
```

My prompt used to show:

```
sashoalm@SASHOALM-PC /c/Workspace/MyProject (master)
```

So something has been "left over" from the unsuccessful patch, how do I completely cancel it, and return to the old prompt?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can abort the process:

```
git am --abort
```

Comment: Thanks :) It was a clear explanation.  Can you also please tell what "am" actually does ?

Comment: @TarunNagpal `git am` takes a patch file (or series of files) and applies them to your current git branch